# Is there any case where datetime.fromtimestamp returns an incorrect result using pytz?

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

`pytz` asks you to use the `.astimezone` method for all time conversion to and from UTC.  However, in one special case — `datetime.fromtimestamp` — it looks like you should be able to use the Python library's datetime methods.

It seems to work here:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> ambigtime = 1352017800  # http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1352017800+unix+time+in+Los+Angeles
>>> amla = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ambigtime, tz=amla)
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 4, 1, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ambigtime + 3600, tz=amla)
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 4, 1, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```

Are there situations where `datetime.fromtimestamp` won't give you the correct results with `pytz` timezones?

Comment: related: [Tips on using python datetime module](http://www.enricozini.org/2009/debian/using-python-datetime/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `pytz.timezone()` will give you an instance of [tzinfo](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo) (or rather a subclass thereof), and as such is totally fine to use with `datetime.fromtimestamp()`.

As long as `pytz` has updated zoneinfo files, you can create localized datetimes using that method. Converting a datetime between two zones however is really loads easier to do with the `astimezone()` method. If I am correct, it basically switches the `tzinfo` property on the datetime.